# How to eliminate the excessive HTTP requests when using pinterest "pin it" buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, pinterest

> Related: [How can i rerender Pinterest's Pin It button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352021/how-can-i-rerender-pinterests-pin-it-button)

---

The design of pinterest **"pin it" button for websites**, shown on [their goodies page](http://pinterest.com/about/goodies/), calls for a web designer to insert a specially-marked  anchor tag into their web page.  Then the page must invoke the [pinit.js boilerplate](http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js).

The special anchor tag must be like this:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?
    url=http%3A%2F%2Fpage%2Furl
    &media=http%3A%2F%2Fimage%2Furl" 
   class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal"></a>
```

and the pinit.js boilerplate must look like this, and must be placed *after* the last pin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js">
</script>
```

As far as I can tell, what the pinit.js code does is this:

- scans the page for anchor tags
- looks for the special markings, specifically the "pin-it-button" class and the href prefix
- replaces the anchor tags with reformatted IFRAMEs.  The  `src` attributes for these iframes get normalized URLs that point to a *different* server, not pinterest.com, but rather a server from the CDN that pinterest uses.

This is fine on a static webpage but:

- it doesn't work on a dynamic page where "pin it" buttons might be dynamically generated via jquery logic and injected into the page markup in response to user actions.
- it requires one iframe per "pin it" button, which means one HTTP GET per "pin it" button.  If you have 10 photos, each with a pinit button, then there are 10 HTTP GETs to pinterests' CDN.  All of these GETs are for similarly-named resources, but they are all slightly different, based on the url of the image to be pinned, and as such cannot be cached.

What I would like to do is eliminate the excessive GETs.  Any ideas?

---

One idea I had was:

- insert exactly one anchor tag, within a div styled as `display:none;`.
- invoke pinit.js, which results in the magic replacement of that anchor tag, and the loading of a new iframe. It is invisible, because it still resides in the invisible div.
- run some additional JS logic to inspect the URL on the src attribute for the generated iframe, saving the hostname for the pinterest CDN.
- ?

I can then generate the "normalized" URLs for the pinterest CDN, but... if I simply use them as src for an iframe *my logic generates*, then I have the same problem with excessive GETs. All I have done is eliminated the successive calls to pinit.js (which is cacheable anyway).

Has anyone confronted this?

I have to believe this design is going to change - it seems not scalable for pinterest the way it works now.

---

**EDIT**

I read [elsewhere](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/03/12/tracking-pinterest-event-tracking/) that pinterest provides an "asynchronous" mechanism for "pin it" buttons on a page, suitable for use when there are lots of "pin it" buttons.  Not sure what that is; I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

I looked but could not find any detailed doc from pinterest that describes how to approach this problem. I think their API is simply too new, too immature to cover this.

The problem I found was that for each "pin it" button, there was a single IFRAME, and that iframe loaded source from the pinterest CDN.  10 images meant 10 iframes and 10 HTTP GETs.

I did find a way to insert a single button on a webpage that allows a user to pin any of the 10 images.  This was via [the pinmarklet.js script, provided by pinterest](http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js).  But, that script didn't work for me, and it had several bugs, so I modified it to suit my purposes.

Now when I click a "pin it" button, it fills only one IFRAME, requires just one HTTP GET, regardless of how many photos are available on a page. The UI looks like this:

[image]

...although you could make it anything you like, I guess.

What problems did I fix?

The pinmarklet was

(a) kludgy. It defined an anonymous script, and a page would need to
      re-request the JS every time it needed to popup the pinterest
      interaction form. No need for that.  Let's just do it once.

(b) broken.  There were several bugs, including a race condition
      in the code that tries to determine the natural size of an image.
      Because of that bug, the pinmarklet form would not show, sometimes.
      Lame!

I modified the code to fix these things, and  it works well now, for me.

http://pastebin.com/y5fBRJHc

Comment: There is no need to edit Pinterest's JS. Check out the linked question and/or [this](http://porizi.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/dynamic-pinterest-button/)

Comment: There is a need to edit the JS if you want to avoid the race condition I mentioned. But maybe pinterest has fixed this problem in the 2 years since I answered this question. It's quite possible.